# How could I do this things in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

- How can I set a CSS parameter in function of a calc? (in my const STYLES I have the property TOP that I want that it be: numberOfMenuItems * -48px).
- How can I set a in const STYLE a param height = $('.contenedor').heigh() (a parameter that depends on the height of a div)?

The code is: (I want add in my constant STYLES this two points on the parametres `top` and `height` as I describe at last of this post)

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationMenu from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/menu';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';


const STYLES = {
title: {
    cursor: 'pointer'
},
titleStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center'
},
displayMenuTrue: {
    position: 'relative'
},  
displayMenuFalse: { 
    display: 'none'
},
contentStyle: {
    transition: 'margin-left 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)',
    marginLeft: '0px',
    top: '0px'
},
contentStyleActive: {
    marginLeft: '256px',
    position: 'relative',
    top: '-144px'
}
};

export default class MenuAlumno extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        drawerOpen:false
   }
}
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar
                title={<span style={STYLES.title}>- PLATAFORMA DE 
INCIDENCIAS -</span>}
                onTitleTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
                titleStyle={STYLES.titleStyle}
            iconElementLeft={this.state.drawerOpen ?  <IconButton>
 <NavigationClose/></IconButton> : <IconButton><NavigationMenu/></IconButton>}
                onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.controlMenu}
            />
            <Drawer 
                open={this.state.drawerOpen}
                containerStyle={this.state.drawerOpen ? 
STYLES.displayMenuTrue : STYLES.displayMenuFalse}
            >
                <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

So... I want this: In my constant STYLES wanna modify (the changes are made on the last element, `contentStyleActive`, the parametres `top` and `height`):

```
const STYLES = {
title: {
    cursor: 'pointer'
},
titleStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center'
},
displayMenuTrue: {
    position: 'relative'
},  
displayMenuFalse: { 
    display: 'none'
},
contentStyle: {
    transition: 'margin-left 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)',
    marginLeft: '0px',
    top: '0px'
},
contentStyleActive: {
    marginLeft: '256px',
    position: 'relative',
    // HERE!
    top: -48px * $('MenuItem').length(),
    height: $('#IdOfMyDiv').heigh() 
}
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function to calculate and add dynamic values to your styles, and the element will have its "style" attribute pointing to that function, something like this:

**EDITED VERSION BELOW:** (added importing jQuery)

*install jquery to your project:*

```
npm install --save jquery
```

Then also *import $ from 'jquery'* :

EDITED VERSION 2: add class-name, for example 'MyClass' to MenuItem component (in render method), then acesss here by $('.MyClass').length instead of $('MenuItem').length . The reason is jQuery wil not understand react-component (which is MenuItem), jQuery will understand DOM: $('.MyClass'), $('#domID') or something like that

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'; 

const STYLES = {
  // ...
  contentStyleActive: {
    marginLeft: '256px',
    position: 'relative',
  }
};

export default class MenuAlumno extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // ...
  }

  contentStyleActiveCalculation(options){
    options.top = parseInt(-48 * $('.MyClass').length) + 'px';
    options.height = $('#IdOfMyDiv').height() + 'px';
    return options;
  }

  render() {
    // ...

    <SomeElement style={this.contentStyleActiveCalculation(STYLES.contentStyleActive)} />

    // ...
  }
}
```

You cannot just add the calculation directly into the const STYLES = {...} declaration, which will be calculated BEFORE elements appear on page (so at that time, jQuery cannot "see" those DOM elements, and cannot know their height or length)

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but is not working for me.. I don't understand why. In principle, everything is fine. I will continue doing research
about why is it.

Comment: No, any error but my Drawer (who is which has this style.contentStyleActive.height() and style.contentStyleActive.top() does not take the correct params. Now I am not at home, but when I arrive, I will do a console.log for see if the px are correct. In this case, the error will be something relationed with Drawer and not due to the syntax. I think that this is the error, as I comment you before, your syntax I think is all fine. I will comment you when I try it! Thank you a lot.

Comment: I've just also tested my code again, seems fine. However, you may need to install jQuery and import it into your page, please see my edit above. Please also feel free to post errors from your console if any, thanks

Comment: Why I have been down-voted ^^ ? I'm trying to help anyway. However, I think the title of this issue is somewhat unrelated, it should be kind of "How to change styles of react component using jQuery"

Comment: I have jQuery installed too. It must be something relationed with Drawer then.. Tomorrow I will continue doing research.

I do not know who down-voted us. I did not do it. I can't due to my reputation. Anybody down-voted you and me...

Comment: This is not Working: `$('MenuItem').length`. MenuItem is not recognized. I don't know why. I add a class into each MenuItem and done: `$('.MyClass').length` and works. Do you know why is not recognized 'MenuItem'?. Thank you.

Comment: And sorry I didn't check it carefully, I just copied from your original code, the part of $('MenuItem'). Actually, $('MenuItem') will not work, because jQuery will not understand React elements, which is MenuItem ^^, jQuery will understand DOM only, that's why $('.className') or $('#domID') or $('tagName') [for example: div, span, img - standard html tags] will work

Comment: @thinhvo0108 That's not true. https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/WjjZLQ

Comment: WoW! then... why in my code does not work??. I copied my code in that web and works fine too!. But in my proyect: length = 0... I do not understand.

Comment: So..the length equals 0 means: there's no such elements of that type on page (maybe that element is too complex which needs more time to render.., if so, we may apply a setTimeout function here, you may say 300ms or even a longer time - 2 or 3 seconds, just to make sure the elements exist on page or not. Finally, you may find the best timeout duration for that!

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery to count the number of items you use the `.length` property.
https://api.jquery.com/length/

To get the height of an element you use `.height()` method. Note: there is also innerHeight() and outerHeight(), depending on whether you want to include an elements padding/margin/border.
http://api.jquery.com/height/

So in your example;

```
top: parseInt(-48 * $('MenuItem').length) + 'px',
height: $('#IdOfMyDiv').height() + 'px'
```

Comment: 1) Have you included/referenced jquery in your project? 
2) Whenever your javascript refers to dom elements you need to include it within the document ready method. $(function() {  console.log( "ready!" ); }); Otherwise you run the risk of the javascript executing before your markup has fully rendered.

Comment: Yes, I did that.